# Django Admin stuck meanwhile DB disk size explode, on object change-view admin panel

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class ActionModel(models.Model):

    identifier = models.BigIntegerField(
        _("identifier"), null=True, blank=True) # target ig id
    username = models.CharField(_("ClientUsername"), max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)  # username of the client
    account_name = models.CharField(_("AccountName"), max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)  # account name of the client
    date = models.DateField(_("Date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)  # action date
    target = models.ForeignKey(Follower, verbose_name=_("Target"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # username of the done-on action
    keyword = models.CharField(_("Keyword"), max_length=150, null=True, blank=True) # the source where this target found
    is_followed_back = models.BooleanField(_("Followed Back"), null=True, blank=True) # is target followed back
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        editable=False
    )  # django user that performed the action

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Action")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Actions")
        unique_together = [
            ['account_name','date','target'],
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.target.username
```

And the following Admin.py:

```
# Custome Admin model for ActionModel Model
class ActionModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # Override queryset method to add count's
    def get_queryset(self, request):

        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.filter(user=request.user)
        return qs

    change_list_template = 'admin/model_history_index.html'
    list_display = [
        'target',
        'account_name',
        'date',
        'keyword',
        'is_followed_back',
    ]

    search_fields = (
        'account_name',
        'keyword',
    )

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

And have really no Idea why when clicking on:
[action admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHMFH.png)

The database free-space is going from 100GB to 0GB !! adding many .temp files on the postgres db folder.
I did some changes and migrate them for this model, mainly adding the "user" field to the action model.
I tried removing the **str** - no help.
also removed the unique_together  - no help.

EDIT:
adding:

```
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

To the admin fixed the issue. but not sure the root couse.

Comment: Could add details on the database (in your post not in comments). Mainly logs when the event occurs.

Comment: Please assist here, which logs ? I am no DB experts. it is on ubuntu machine.

Comment: Well, I am trying to assist but without insights, how could we help? You are saying your database have space issue, how do you know it? What DB it is? Then try to find where your log is and post it. That will be a good start.